# Why isn't .reverse() working?

Tags: python, list, reverse

I am trying to take a sentence and split that sentence, reverse it, and print it to the screen.

I am having trouble understanding how `.reverse()` works?
When I do something like:

```
test = ['This','is','a','test']
new_test = test.reverse()
print(new_test)
```

When I run this I am getting `None`, why is this? How can I make `.reverse()` work?

Here is my final code:

```
sentence = input("What is your sentence? ")
split_sentence = sentence.split().reverse()
for word in sentence:
    print(word,end='')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reverse()` operates in place, and doesn't return a new array. If you want to use a copy, you'll need to do the following:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
copy = arr.copy() # omit this if you don't want a new list
copy.reverse()
# copy now contains [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
# arr still contains [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Interesting why exactly does it python make it operate "in-place" like this? Seems much more confusing.

Comment: Ultimately it comes down to the way reversing a list is implemented in C, which is quite simple to do in place.

Answer (score 5):

`reverse()` reverses a list in-place, and returns `None`. Just print your original list:

```
test = ['This','is','a','test']
test.reverse() # In-place!
print(test)
```

Comment: Interesting why exactly does it python make it operate "in-place" like this? Seems much more confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `slicing`

```
test = ['This','is','a','test']
>>> print(test[::-1])
['test', 'a', 'is', 'This']
```

Answer (score 3):

`reverse()` function performs in place reversal of a list and that's reason you're getting `None` in `new_test` list. You can use following snippet to have reversed list.

```
from copy import deepcopy

test = ['This','is','a','test']
new_test = deepcopy(test)
print(new_test)
new_test.reverse()
print(new_test)
```

**output:**

```
['This', 'is', 'a', 'test']
['test', 'a', 'is', 'This']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print([ele for ele in reversed(list1)])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[6,5,4,3,2,1]
```